# jQuery - get id of a nested single <li> element when right click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I found a lot of questions about this, but I have problem with getting the single id of a nested `li` element, and I couldn't find answer for it. Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul').on('contextmenu', 'li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id);
 });
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="u-main-ul">
    <li id="1"> 1
        <ul id="u-1">
            <li id="11">11</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when I right click on the `li` element with `id="11"`, on the console it writes "1 11". When click one `li` element it shows and the id of all others `li` tags that are placed before the clicked one.

I want to get the id only of the right-clicked `li` tag and nothing else.

Comment: do you know how deep are the nested lists ? would it be dynamicly generated, or is it a hardcoded menu ?

Comment: it will be as deep as the client goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event from bubbling up the tree:

```js
$('ul').on('contextmenu', 'li', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="u-main-ul">
  <li id="1">1
    <ul id="u-1">
      <li id="11">11</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) like so

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('contextmenu', 'li', function(e) { 
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log(this.id);
   })
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwhbmvqs/)